# Show that the probability: $P(A^c \cup C) \geq 7/8$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $A,B,C$ be pairwise independent events with $P(A \cap B) = 0.1$ and $ P(B\cap C)=0.2$. Show that $P(A^c \cup C) \geq 7/8$.

This is what I could do

Since $P(B) \geq 2/10$ and $P(A)P(B)=1/10$, $P(A) \leq 0.5$ and $1-P(C) \leq 4/5$ so $P(A \cap C^c) \leq 2/5$ i.e $P(A^c \cup C) \geq 3/5$

Comment: use venn diagram

Comment: how is p(b)>0.2

Comment: its P(B) >=0.2, that was a typo initially, I had already edited it

Answer (score 2):

From $P(A\cap B)=0.1$ and $P(B\cap C)=0.2$, we get $P(C)=2P(A)$,

$$\begin{align}P(A^c \cup C)&=P(A^c)+P(C)-P(A^c\cap C)\\
\\
&=1-P(A)+P(C)-(1-P(A))\cdot P(C)\\
\\
&=1-P(A)+P(A)P(C)\\
\\
&=1-P(A)+2P(A)^2\\
\\
&=2\left(P(A)-\frac14\right)^2+\frac78
\\
\\&\ge\frac78\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since the complement of $A^c\cup C=A\cap C^c$, we are reduced to show that $\mathbb P(A\cap C^c)\leqslant 1/8$. By independence between $A$ and $C^c$, it suffices to show that
$$
\tag{*} \mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(C^c) \leqslant 1/8
$$

By pairwise independence, the assumptions on $A\cap B$ and $B\cap C$ translate as $\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B)=1/10$ and $\mathbb P(B)\mathbb P(C)=2/10$ hence
$\mathbb P(A)/\mathbb P(C)=1/2$.
Therefore, (*) reduces to $\mathbb P(C)\mathbb P(C^c) \leqslant 1/4$, which follows from $t(1-t)\leqslant 1/4$ for each $t\in [0,1]$.